# How to automate website with same buttons and same class? the difference is only the onlick of HTML

Tags: javascript, selenium, automation, web

The first button is

```
<button class="btn bid-hotel-btn" type="button" onclick="buyNow(0,false)">Beli Sekarang</button>
```

and the second button is

```
<button class="btn bid-hotel-btn" type="button" onclick="buyNow(1,false)">Beli Sekarang</button>
```

The difference is only the `onlick` event on `HTML` and I want to automatically click one button.

Comment: You should provide complete `HTML` for mentioned buttons

Comment: How will you determine which button to click? It would probably be helpful to have more of the surrounding HTML for the buttons. You will likely want to reference a button by it's container element(s).

Comment: Although the attributes for those two buttons are identical, but their locations in the HTML page have to be different. You can still locate them by using Xpath. If you want any help with Xpath, you need to provide us with the HTML code as well.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `XPath`

```
//button[@onclick="buyNow(0,false)"]
```

for first button. And

```
//button[@onclick="buyNow(1,false)"]
```

for second

Answer (score 0):

I do not know much about javascript, but you can still use this example below as a reference:

you can locate multiple elements that share similar (or identical) attributes using:

```
twoButtons = find_elements_by_css_selector("button[class='btn bid-hotel-btn']")
```

Provided this class attribute is unique, if it is not unique, you can combine more attributes together to narrow it down. E.g.

```
twoButtons = find_elements_by_css_selector("button[class='btn bid-hotel-btn'][type='button']")
```

**twoButtons** should contains two web element of the buttons you want to click.

Then you address each one button in this twoButtons list, e.g.:

```
twoButtons[0].click() //click the first button
twoButtons[1].click() //click the second button
```

**What did I mean by "`first`" and "`second`" above?**

**`First`** button will appear **above** **`second`** button in their HTML hierarchy.

Comment: why you use `0` and `2` indexes for first and second buttons?:) I guess it should be `0` and `1`

Comment: @Andersson, sharp eye, my mistake. will correct it now